# MBean persistence

Tags: java, spring, jmx, jboss5.x

I have a problem with persistence of my config MBean. My configuration:

```
<bean id="adminMBean" class="pl.mobileexperts.catchme.mbeans.AdminSettingsMBean"></bean>

<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="assembler" ref="assembler" />
    <property name="autodetect" value="true" />
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="attributeSource" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource" />
<bean id="namingStrategy" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.MetadataNamingStrategy">
    <property name="attributeSource" ref="attributeSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="assembler" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
    <property name="attributeSource" ref="attributeSource" />
</bean>
```

---

```
 @ManagedResource(objectName = "pl.mobileexperts.catchme:name=adminMBean",
 description  ="admin settings",
 persistPolicy = "OnUpdate",
 persistLocation = "c:/", persistName = "adminSettings.jmx")
 public class AdminSettingsMBean {

      private boolean moderatorModeEnabled;

      public AdminSettingsMBean() {
      }

      @ManagedAttribute(persistPolicy = "OnUpdate")
      public boolean isModeratorModeEnabled() {
        return moderatorModeEnabled;
      }

      @ManagedAttribute(persistPolicy = "OnUpdate")
      public void setModeratorModeEnabled(boolean moderatorModeEnabled) {
        this.moderatorModeEnabled = moderatorModeEnabled;
      }
 }
```

My goal is to save state after a property change (save to file or metadata - not to db). After a JBoss restart, my MBean is initialized with standard values. It seems PersistPolicy is not working... I tried to implement PersistentMBean, but store() and load() were never invoked. I found that it may be a JBoss JMX implementation issue. Also some people used AOP and annotated methods in MBean to store them. All these posts were from 2008-2010, so maybe something has changed?

My JBoss config is default (jboss-service.xml)

Comment: Which version of JBoss are you using? Does it support `persistPolicy`?

Comment: jboss-5.1.0.GA
https://community.jboss.org/thread/175100?tstart=0 i keep searching

Comment: For some bizzare reason I don't really know, this page https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/PersistentMBean.html tells me that onUpdate will indeed not call store(). Try change to always and see if helps. (I'm trully shocked too)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the JBoss implementation of JMX. According to JSR160, specifying `persistPolicy=OnUpdate` for an attribute should result in persisting every time the attribute is updated (from [JSR160 1.4](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jmx_remote-1_4-mrel2-spec/)):

> persistPolicy - Defines the default persistence policy for attributes in this MBean
>   that do not define their own persistPolicy. Takes on one of the following values:
>
> [...]
>
> - OnUpdate - The attribute is stored every time the attribute is updated.

It is most likely caused by this very strange text in Sun's Javadoc for `PersistMBean` (as pointed out by [@Plínio Pantaleão](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233751/pl%C3%ADnio-pantale%C3%A3o)):

> Do not store the MBean if 'persistPolicy' field is:
>
> = "never"
>
> = "onUpdate"
>
> = "onTimer" && now < 'lastPersistTime' + 'persistPeriod'

Other than reporting this to JBoss (and the Javadoc issue to Sun), you may be able to work around it by using `persistPolicy=Always` policy (again, from JSR160):

> - Always - This is a synonym of OnUpdate, which is recognized for
>     compatibility reasons. It is recommended that applications use OnUpdate
>     instead. An implementation of the Descriptor interface, such as
>     DescriptorSupport, can choose to replace a value of “Always” for
>     persistPolicy by a value of “OnUpdate”.